# foreach associative array not accessible index not proper

Tags: php

```
foreach($ev as $evn)
{
    $events[]=array(
    "event"=>$evn['EVTID']  
    );


}
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [event] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [event] => 2 ) )
```

I have access 3 and 2 value

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clear your question.

Comment: i need to access the [event]=>3  And [event]=>2 value the value that contains 3 and 2 i have access those values

Comment: $en="SELECT tsmrep.REPID,tsmrep.EVTID,tsmrep.RMTID,tsmrep.RMTIN,tsmrep.REAEP,tsmrap.RAPID,tsmrla.URAID,tsmrla.CLNID,tsmrla.CPJID,tsmrla.RURID FROM ((tsmrla INNER JOIN tsmrep ON tsmrep.RMTID=tsmrla.RMTID) INNER JOIN tsmrap ON tsmrla.RMTID=tsmrap.RMTID) WHERE RURID='$id' AND REAEP='1'";
     $req = $bdd->prepare($en);
     $req->execute();
     
     $ev = $req->fetchAll();
     
     if(!empty($ev))
     {
      
      
      foreach($ev as $evn)
      {
       $events[]=array(
       "event"=>$evn['EVTID'] 
       );
      
       
      } this is my code

Comment: i need to access the [event]=>3 And [event]=>2 value the value that contains 3 and 2 i  cannot access 3 and 2 these values

Comment: `$events[0]['event']` and `$events[1]['event']` are probably what you need

Comment: how i check this if (in_array(3, $events, true)) {
      echo "'3' found with strict check\n";
      }

Comment: how i check this if (in_array(3, $events, true)) {
      echo "'3' found with strict check\n";
      } the 3 is present in array but the statement can't print